# Do IE comments in HTML trigger quirks mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I'm prepping to launch something this upcoming week and I was under the belief that everything was complete until I viewed the site in IE.

I'm completely novice to all this stuff and am just learning. I decided to do some searching and attempt to fix it. I still don't fully understand Quirks mode, but I came across this comment that said Quirks mode in any version of IE will also be triggered if anything but whitespace precedes the DOCTYPE, including comments.

I don't have anything preceding DOCTYPE-- but am curious if comments trigger quirks mode regardless? Here is the current code to view:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Lunity Inc.</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" id="styles" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.onbile.com/redirection/77kzusf6mr3skx3ctwqt18n6fgzuc47meo0qeccyexto4fovio">   </script>
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link media="screen,projection" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link media="screen,projection" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/full_bg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery(".bg").fullBg();
    });
  </script>
 </head>
```

If this is accepted then why is my site appearing different in IE? In IE8 it looks as if css isn't applied at all and in IE9 the font is off as well as the font size.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using any DOCTYPE ? (If not you should )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

[Yes] Any character before DOCTYPE might make IE going quircks mode ...

Comment shouldn't trigger the quircksmode (except if one is placed before doctype :p )

Comment: "I don't have anything preceding DOCTYPE"

Comment: @NaNisNoTNuLL my apologies-- yes I am using DOCTYPE, just wasn't copied. Is there any other explanation as to why the site isn't appearing the way it should in IE?

Comment: @david-roman Can you give me the URL so that I could inspect ? Notice : 'Content-Type' meta  should be placed before the title :)

Comment: @david-roman Nothing strange apparently ... You can strip js and css ref, test rendering in IE, then append each of them and test one by one ...

Comment: @NaNisNoTNuLL what browser did you run it in?

Comment: IE, which did not appreciated your site at all (Error dialog prompted ...) and Firefox which did spent loads of time rendering the page ... I don't think my location is the only responsible for those problems `:p` almost 2:30 am ... good luck then !

Comment: @NaNisNoTNuLL yea, the image im using is large so it takes a bit to load-- I've made some changes to speed it up but am yet to upload the latest version with the changes. Everything was functional in FF though, right?